# Access a value set up by `beforeAll` during tests

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, memoization, hspec, test-fixture

Here's what I've got:

```
spec :: Spec
spec = do
  manager <- runIO newManager

  it "foo" $ do
    -- code that uses manager

  it "bar" $ do
    -- code that usees manager
```

The docs for `runIO` suggest that I should probably be using `beforeAll` instead, since I do not need `manager` to *construct* the spec tree, I just need it to *run* each test, and in my use case it's better for them to all share the same manager rather than creating a new one for each test.

> If you do not need the result of the IO action to construct the spec tree, beforeAll may be more suitable for your use case.

```
beforeAll :: IO a -> SpecWith a -> Spec
```

But I can't figure out how to access the manager from the tests.

```
spec :: Spec
spec = beforeAll newManager go

go :: SpecWith Manager
go = do
  it "foo" $ do
    -- needs "manager" in scope
  it "bar" $ do
    -- needs "manager" in scope
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spec arguments are passed to your it blocks as regular function arguments (look at the associated type of the `Example` type class, if you want to understand what's going on).  A fully self-contained example would be:

```
import           Test.Hspec

main :: IO ()
main = hspec spec

spec :: Spec
spec = beforeAll (return "foo") $ do
  describe "something" $ do
    it "some behavior" $ \xs -> do
      xs `shouldBe` "foo"

    it "some other behavior" $ \xs -> do
      xs `shouldBe` "foo"
```